# Open a form inside another form ?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two Forms named **mainForm** and **helperForm**. On mainForm I have a button and on helperForm I have a richTextBox. What I want to do is; once the button on the mainForm is clicked I would like to display helperForm, as well as some text on the richtextbox. With below code I am able to see the helper form, but text coming after the button finish all the process that goes inside the **buttonClick** event...

**MainForm**

```
public partial class Form : Form 
{
   public HelperForm helperForm;

   public MainForm()
   {
     InitializeComponent(); 
   }  

   public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     helperForm= new HelperForm ();
     helperForm.Show();    

     helperForm.richTextBox1.AppendText("Program started");

     //doing  process1  
     helperForm.richTextBox1.AppendText("Program start to check process1");

     //doing process2  
     helperForm.richTextBox1.AppendText("Program start to check process2");

     //doing process3  
     helperForm.richTextBox1.AppendText("Program start to check process3");

     //doing process2  
     helperForm.richTextBox1.AppendText("All the process are done!");

     helperForm.Close();
}
```

Comment: If you want to execute a lot of code from a Click event handler then you'll need to use threads to avoid that code from making the user interface unresponsive.  Inserting helperForm.Update() calls is a very imperfect but simple workaround.

Comment: @HansPassant I did removed the helperForm.Close() but still text coming after all the processes are done.

Comment: Your code snippet is very unclear, it is hiding the real problem.  That code we cannot see that prevents the controls from painting themselves.  As noted, calling helperForm.Update() after every AppendText() call forces the controls to paint so you can see it.  I strongly recommend a book about Winforms programming, understanding this is not trivial and very important to get ahead with writing proper GUI code.

Comment: You can call helperForm.Show() after appending text in the richtextbox.

Comment: In the simplest terms, the user interface will not update until after an event-triggered method is finished running. Since all the code is in a single button click event handler, you will not see anything that you are expecting to see. This is the purpose of background threads in a UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
    public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        helperForm= new HelperForm (); 
        Timer countdown=new Timer();
        countdown.Interval=1000;//1000 Milliseconds
        countdown.Tick+=CountDownTickEvent;

        switch(condition to check which text to append):
        {
        case 1:
        helperForm.richTextBox1.AppendText("Program started");
        break;

        case 2:
        //doing  process1  
        helperForm.richTextBox1.AppendText("Program start to check process1");
        break;

        case 3:
        //doing process2  
        helperForm.richTextBox1.AppendText("Program start to check process2");
        break;

        case 4:
        //doing process3  
        helperForm.richTextBox1.AppendText("Program start to check process3");
        break; 

        case 5:
        //doing process2  
        helperForm.richTextBox1.AppendText("All the process are done!");
        break;
        } 

        helperForm.Show();

     }
```

You are displaying a form modelessly,it means this one is not going to block the caller thread so there's no reason to call `Form.Close()` 6 statements later than `Form.Show()`,it makes no sense,this just displays the form for flash and then the form disapperars.If you need to show the form for a specified duration better use a `Timer`.

**Edit :** To show the form for a specified duration use the function below;

```
    int counter=0;
    public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        helperForm= new HelperForm (); 
        Timer countdown=new Timer();//New instance of Timer class.
        countdown.Interval=1000;//1000 Milliseconds,change as needed.
        countdown.Tick+=CountDownTickEvent;//Event handler for tick event of Timer.

        //Same as above.

        helperForm.Show();
        countdown.Start();//Start the timer.
     }
```

Then create the `CountDownTickEvent` as below one;

```
    private void CountDownTickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter == 5)//5 seconds have been passed since the timer is running.Change as needed.
        {
            helperForm.Close();//Displayed for 5 seconds,form should close now.
            counter=0;
        }
    }
```

Well,that gives you a **helperForm** for 5 seconds with the text and then it closes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to use a background thread to achieve a 'progress bar' type of display, which prevents locking the UI. When commanding UI actions from a background thread, you need to invoke those actions to prevent exceptions - UI updated are not allowed directly from background threads.

The following code does what you want, but you need to read up on threading, invoking and delegates or this will not make any sense. If we could see more of your code there might be a way to use Application.DoEvents(), but that's more appropriate in a loop that gives a good place to repeat the command. I still prefer background threads unless I'm throwing together a small utility program.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private HelperForm helperForm;
    private Thread processRunner;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (processRunner == null || processRunner.ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped)
        {
            helperForm = new HelperForm();
            helperForm.Show();

            processRunner = new Thread(new ThreadStart(runProcesses));
            processRunner.Start();
        }
    }

    private void runProcesses()
    {


        this.Invoke(new Action( () => { helperForm.richTextBox1.AppendText("Program started"); }));

        //represents  process1
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        this.Invoke(new Action( () => { helperForm.richTextBox1.AppendText("Program start to check process1"); }));

        //represents process2  
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        this.Invoke(new Action( () => { helperForm.richTextBox1.AppendText("Program start to check process2"); }));

        //represents process3  
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        this.Invoke(new Action(() => { helperForm.richTextBox1.AppendText("Program start to check process3"); }));

        //represents process4  
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        this.Invoke(new Action(() => { helperForm.richTextBox1.AppendText("All the process are done!"); }));

        // to let the message display
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        helperForm.Invoke(new Action(() => { helperForm.Close(); }));
    }
}
```